# Making proof rigorous that isometries of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are bijective using balls

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, isometry

I was wondering how the proof of the fact that isometries of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are bijective could be made rigorous using the following argument. I understand that there is a more general (topological) argument involving isometries of compact metric spaces, but I'm doing this as a practice question for a class on groups (we prove if $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is an isometry it is bijective, and thus that the set of all such isometries forms a group under composition).

The argument (for surjectivity, injectivity is fine) goes as follows:
Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and consider $B_{\delta}(x) = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^n : d(x,y) < \delta \} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ the open ball of radius $\delta$ around $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now since $f$ is an isometry, $f(B_{\delta}(x)) = B_{\delta}(x+a)$, where $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$. That is, $f$ is a translation of $B_{\delta}(x)$ since $f$ is distance preserving. Now if we let $\delta \rightarrow \infty$, any $p\in \mathbb{R}^n$ will eventually be in some $B_{\delta}(x)$ as this ball will fill $\mathbb{R}^n$. Thus $\exists q \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(q) = p$ and hence $f$ is surjective. Then as $f$ is injective and surjective, $f$ is a bijection.

I'm wondering how this argument could be made more rigorous. The proof for injectivity and that this does form a group under composition is fine, just that this part is a little trickier and I was wondering if anyone had any advice for this.

Comment: Unfortunately, $f$ being an isometry tells you only that $f(B_\delta(x)) \subseteq B_\delta(f(x))$. You fail to obtain $\supseteq$ in infinite-dimensions, for example. If this can be shown through topology, it will take an argument that uses properties peculiar to finite dimensions (e.g. compactness of the closed unit ball?).

Comment: It seems like this argument asserts that every isometry is a translation. (There is a possible typo of “if” for “of,” so I may be mistaken.) This is certainly not true, since reflections are isometries.

Comment: @TheoBendit right, but since I am considering only the case in which $f$ is a map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to itself we are working only in finite dimensions, no?

Comment: @SteveKass Right of course, so I should fix this by possibly having some orthogonal operation on $B_{\delta}(x)$ also? As I understand it, it turns out isometries of $\mathbb{R}^n$ turn out to be the affine maps, but I was trying to use a different argument.

Comment: Of course; I'm just saying that you *may* need to go into the anatomy of $\Bbb{R}^n$, or the linear structure of finite-dimensional vector spaces, if you want your proof to work. At some point in your proof, you've got to actually use the assumption that you're in finite-dimensional space, otherwise the infinite-dimensional spaces will be a counterexample to your arguments!

Comment: My apologies; I must have missed the last part of your comment. I see what you're saying now - definitely a useful suggestion - perhaps such an argument can't be made without invoking some properties from topology. Certainly you're right that I will need to use the fact that it's finite dimensional - thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: My guess is that you read my comment before I edited it. Sorry. :-)